# Attaching a database to SQL Server (Management Studio) - Error 5

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to attached a database from a previous company to a new SQL Server. The `.mdf` and `.ldf` files are both saved to my desktop.

When I try to attach the database, I get the following error:

[image]

I have attached this database before, with no problem.

Comment: The message is very clear here: *"Access is denied."* The Service account does not have access to the location `C:\DATA\Promigen (Test) DB\ ` or the file(s) contained within it.

Comment: @Larnu how do I correct this?

Comment: Grant the Service account access to the directory `C:\DATA\Promigen (Test) DB\ ` and the files within it, or place the files in a location that the Service Account does have access to.

Comment: @Larnu thank you. Sorted :)